# Unable to attach a response header in ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock()

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

In my Play 2.6 application, I have a custom action class that does some common things, applicable to all my actions. Omitting the unrelated details, the code looks like this:

```
class VariantAction @Inject()
  (parser: BodyParsers.Default)
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) 
extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) with Results {

   ///
   override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
      if (aok) {
            block(request).andThen {
              case Success(result) =>                
                  result.withHeaders("foo" -> "bar")   // THIS DOES NOT WORK
              case Failure(t) =>
            }
         }
         catch {
              /// Some exception handling
         }
      }
      else {
         Future.successful(ServiceUnavailable)
      }
   }
}
```

All works as expected: the callback in andThen() gets executed, but the header it attempts to add to the response is not added. I imagine there's a race condition and by the time the callback is called the response is already committed. Of course I can add this logic to all concrete actions, but that seems to defy reason.

Answer (score 1):

Andriy's answer contains the explanation of why my code didn't work, but not a consumable answer how to fix it: the root of the problem, as Andriy points out, is my misunderstanding of the Result.withHeaders() method: it's not a mutator, but rather produces a new Result object.

This works:

```
class VariantAction @Inject()
  (parser: BodyParsers.Default)
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) 
extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) with Results {

   ///
   override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
      if (aok) {
         block(request).map { _.withHeaders("foo" -> "bar") }
         }
         catch {
              /// Some exception handling
         }
      }
      else {
         Future.successful(ServiceUnavailable)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Construction `block(request).andThen ...` return just a `result` it does not return the result with a header `"foo"`. aka it returns the result of `block(request)`, not the result of `.andThen`. The callback in the `.andThen` will work eventually, thought the result will not be returned.

Try to change `andThen` to `map`. `andThen` is for "side effect" and "map" is for "transformation" result.

Here the difference:

[image]

You also need to be sure you do not override "foo" header later in the action.